# How can I remove the initial return when the multiple texts are added to the field?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am asking the user to select a txt file from a specified folder on a server [This is in PowerPoint 2007], but I need to give them the option of selecting more than one, so I have a bit of conditional code to determine this.

One file selected uses this code:

```
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Text
```

More than one file selected currently uses this:

```
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Text
```

…but this results in an extra return space above it all in the field, which is a bit untidy.

Could anyone advise me on how I can modify this to only get the returns in between the two texts, but not at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I got the problem, but I believe this will do:

```
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = iif(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text <> "", oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf,  "") & Text
```

Comment: oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf works, but leaves returns after it. I'll try yours, but what's the Nz for?

Comment: I'd be happy to go with my own solution above, but I need to find aw way to remove the last two returns from the field.

Comment: Nz catches the case where the field is null, not just an empty string. It's just to be safe/ The iif statement will check if there is already a value in your oShape, and if yes, append 2 lines and then the text, otherwise just the text. Did you try it?

Comment: The Nz errors with 'Sub or function not defined.' Is there a specific function that should be called?

Comment: Interesting. Sorry I supposed vba would have the same functions across platforms. You can skip that I guess. <Code edited>

Comment: I find differences in each version of Office. Microsoft do like to change things. If I can get the count of paragraphs in the text field, I can probably work out how to remove the last returns.

Comment: Paragraphs in the text field:  oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count